# Spark Streaming Kafka Receivers API - numPartitions

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are using spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 Receivers. We are not able to increase the amount of consumed events by increasing numPartitions. It seems increasing numPartitions doesn't affect the performance.

The KafkaUtils.createStream method has a topic_name to numPartitions map, while  each partition should be consumed in its own thread.

Currently we are working with:

```
KafkaUtils.createStream[Integer, Event, IntegerDecoder, EventDecoder](ssc,
  Configuration.kafkaConfig, scala.collection.immutable.Map(topic -> 1),
  StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

I would expect using scala.collection.immutable.Map(topic -> 10) will pull much more events than when using 1 thread, but it doesn't improve the performance (I made sure that 10 threads are in fact used per receiver)

However, If I create more Kafka receivers (which from my understanding is exactly equivalent to increasing threads) the performance **does improve**.

Is this a problem with version 0-8? 
Should increasing numPartitions improve amount of consumed events?
Why does adding receivers improve performance while increasing numPartition doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a problem with version 0-8?

No, it is a "problem" with **the receiver based approach**, which is what you're using with `createStream`. The said approach will create a single thread for consumption on a given executor node. If you want to read concurrently, you have to create multiple such receivers.

Per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html):

> Topic partitions in Kafka does not correlate to partitions of RDDs
>   generated in Spark Streaming. So increasing the number of
>   topic-specific partitions in the KafkaUtils.createStream() only
>   increases the number of threads using which topics that are consumed
>   within a single receiver. It does not increase the parallelism of
>   Spark in processing the data

If you want to increase concurrency, use the direct (receiverless) based approach (using `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`) which dispatches a each `TopicPartition` to a given executor node for consumption, thus allowing all executors to participate in consuming from Kafka